# How to create directional two pointed arrow using css?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

How can I make this line with doubled arrow?

I've seen a few tutorials that teach you how to create boxes with arrows, however, in my case, none of those tutorials are suitable.

[image]

Comment: best way to do something specific is to use an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this using pure css.(Quite easy and simple way which supports all browsers).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="arrow-left"></span>
  <span class="arrow-right"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
width:60%; 
height:40px; 
background:#ccc; 
margin:100px auto;
}
.arrow-right {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 40px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
border-left: 40px solid #ccc;
float:right;
margin-top:-20px;
margin-right:-40px;
}

.arrow-left {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top:40px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 40px solid transparent; 
float:left;
border-right:40px solid #ccc;
margin-top:-20px;
margin-left:-40px;
}
```

**Working Fiddle**

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yej79vhq/)</kbd>

**Update**

You can also try to make this with pseudo classes like :before,:after but they have some browser compatibility in IE. (I will not prefer this method but it is an easy way).

Comment: thanks for the fast response, I will use this implementation twice to have the border

Answer (score 2):

First of all, those css3 arrows are more a proof of concept than anything else. You should not use them for serious reasons. Either way, to do this you would have to create the center box, and then use a `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to draw the two arrows. Not going to do the work for you of course though. Only problem is that doing it this way will not include the border, as the border is normally in those tricks an underlying triangle of slightly bigger size. In other words, if you want it including the border it's not possible with a single element anymore and you would need to use two overlapping elements... or just an image or `svg`.

Comment: @XandrUu: Wasn't addressing you, but the downvoter ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/3hfz8r8r/1/

```
.arrow {
    background: red;
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px #000);
}

.arrow:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid red;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -30px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
}

.arrow:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid red;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    right: -30px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
}
```

with a markup like that:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/3hfz8r8r/1/

Comment: your example looks like a table

Comment: @SamDenton Check on chrome I only add webkit prefixes (update the prefixes)

Comment: ah, makes sense, btw, works on ie if you set top on each arrow to -80% instead of 50%