# How to add red Arrow with text in CSS

Tags: html, css

Given the following code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.abs_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent_div">
      abc
      <div class="abs_div">yoyo</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

We got
[image]

Please refer the code at https://codepen.io/jackee1234/pen/dydMbxE

How should I add the portion highlighted in green rectangle?
[image]

Comment: `padding: 100px 50px` ?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti I mean draw the arrow and text (it's already 100px and 50px)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526174/how-to-create-directional-two-pointed-arrow-using-css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create directional two pointed arrow using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526174/how-to-create-directional-two-pointed-arrow-using-css)

Answer (score 2):

use more div to create similar output. Hope this help

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.abs_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.dot{
  height:5px;
  width:5px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.dot.nothing{
 margin-bottom:0;
}
.dot2{
  height:5px;
  width:5px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-right:5px;
  flex:none;
}

.dot2.nothing{
 margin-right:0;
}

.group{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
}



.group2{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 margin-top:20px;
}

.the100{
  height:calc(100px - 6px);
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:60px;
  border:3px dashed #F6F454;
}
.the100 .word{
 position:absolute;
 top:40px;
  color:#fff;
}
.the50{
  height:50px;
  width:calc(50px - 6px);
  position:absolute;
  top:130px;
  left:0px;
  border:3px dashed #F6F454;
}

.the50 .word{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent_div">
      abc
      <div class="the100">
      <div class="group">
        <i class="arrow up"></i>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot nobottom"></div>
        <i class="arrow down"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="word">100px</div>
      </div>
      <div class="the50">
      <div class="group2">
        <i class="arrow left"></i>
        <div class="dot2"></div>
        <div class="dot2 nobottom"></div>
        <i class="arrow right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="word">50px</div>
      </div>
      <div class="abs_div">yoyo</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, why do you put `-webkit-transform:` on top of `transform`, is it because some browser only support `-webkit-transform:` rather than  `transform`?

Comment: it doesn't matter , top or bottom, but yes, you are correct, some browser support and some don't

Comment: @william007 `-webkit-`, `-o`, `-ms` etc. are called prefixes and will give better browser support, mostly for legacy browsers, but can also be relevant for modern browsers. you can use https://caniuse.com/?search=transform to see browser support for specific properties

Answer (score 0):

Here.... you have to make a div then in that div make 3 more div, 2 for triangles and 1 for that dashed line , similarly for another one.. once your arrows are ready, give position:absolute; and give its position... and for text you can do this like arrows(giving its position).... do you want full code or you can make it yourself? but for making triangles ,here's code:

Html:

```
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

css:

```
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  
  border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
  
  border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

this is the website for more: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

hope this will help you,thank you

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ? i dont know if you want it to be overflown the use this . otherwise comment below and i will code accordingly.

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .parent_div {
        position: relative;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: steelblue;
      }

      .abs_div {
        background-color: greenyellow;
        width: 50%;
        height: calc(100vh - 200px);
        width:calc(100vw - 100px);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent_div">
      <div class="abs_div">yoyo</div>
    </div>
   
  </body>
</html>
```